# how to know if a vector's highest number is even or odd (C++14)

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code which gets a string from the user, and it will find the digits and put them in a vector. Then it will find the highest number in the vector.

Question: How should I edit it so it would find if its even or odd?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if(isdigit(str[i])){
            vec.push_back(str[i]);
        }
    }
    int max = *max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    if(max / 2 == 0){
        cout << "is even";
    } else {
        cout << "is odd";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i want an output such as this:

input:

```
Hgj326nm2tgh21salamcup
```

output:

```
is even
```

or

input:

```
eMok2404fggh5987fgf52fgf21
```

output:

```
is odd
```

Comment: `(int)(vec[i]); // this will turn ascii numbers to an int, idk how` <-- that code doesn't do anything at all; the items in a `vector<int>` were already ints, so casting one of them to int again is redundant, and in any case the result of the expression is discarded.

Comment: *"input:

    `Hgj326nm2tgh21salamcup`"* -- before testing complex cases, try a simple one. What should the output be for the input `2`? What is the actual output? What is the value of `max` in this case?

Comment: `max/2 == 0` does not test if the value of `max` is even or odd.   It tests if `max/2` (with rounding toward zero) is equal to zero, which is not the same thing.   You need to compute the *remainder* and test that.    Also, the `*max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end())` in your code gives undefined behaviour if `vec` has no elements.

Answer (score 2):

> how to know if a vector's highest number is even or odd

You should replace the statement `vec.push_back(str[i]);` with:

```
//-------------------vvvvv----->subtract '0'
vec.push_back(str[i] - '0');
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/8bISYAh5P)

##### Explanation

`'0'` is a [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal). Here both `str[i]` and `'0'` will be promoted to `int`. And the final result that is added(appended)  into the vector will be the result of subtraction of those two promoted `int` values. Moreover, it is **guaranteed** by the [C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.charset) that:

> 3. ...In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>    each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>    one greater than the value of the previous.

This means that the difference between the two will give us the number that the character `str[i]` represents.

---

Additionally there is no need for having the following statement:

```
(int)(vec[i]);//no need for this statement
```

---

Also note that `if(max / 2 == 0)` should be:

```
//-----v---------->note the modulus
if(max % 2 == 0)
```

---

Also refer to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)